# CSS-спрайты и border-image

Tags: css

Я пытаюсь делать кое-какое веб-приложение и мне нужно, чтобы текстуры всех элементов гуи хранились в виде одного изображения (скина). С одной картинкой удобно работать и это оптимизирует трафик. Для текстурирования гуи я использую технологию, именуемую [CSS-спрайтами](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-sprite), кроме того, мне не обойтись без [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) для декорации различных окошек и кнопочек. Так вот, я не понимаю, как мне указать в качестве src для border-image **часть** изображения, ведь это не background-image, его нельзя сдвинуть!

Если CSS-спрайты вообще никак не применимы к border-image, подскажите пожалуйста альтернативное решение.

Comment: Как вариант - конвертировать картинки в base64 и зашивать их в CSS. Это еще сильнее оптимизирует трафик (если это небольшие изображения) и с такими изображениями удобнее работать, чем со спрайтами.

Comment: @terron да, я думал об этом, но оптимизация трафика не единственная причина, по которой я хочу использовать CSS-спрайты. Дело в том, что  это и в разработке очень удобно. То ли я буду одну картинку держать открытой и видеть на ней все элементы и их соотношения в размерах, то ли сотню по отдельности.

Comment: Что вам мешает в продакшн зашивать всё в base64, а для себя любимого создавать спрайты, на которые будете смотреть в ходе разработки?

Comment: Ну мне хотелось бы иметь возможность на лету по-быстрому что-то менять и сразу видеть результат.